# How to add wildcard to DNS for wordpress multisite in Kloxo?

Tags: wildcard, wordpress, wildcard-subdomain

I want to add Wildcard to DNS in my VPS (for setup Wordpress3.3.2 multisite). I have Kloxo, and when i want to add it from Manage DNS ( in Domain Adm ), i face with this error.

```
Alert: invalid_subdomain
```

Also i removed:

```
// Validates subdomain
if (!preg_match("/^(([a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$/", $param['hostname'])) {
throw new lxexception('invalid_subdomain', 'hostname');
}
```

from /usr/local/lxlabs/kloxo/httpdocs/htmllib/lib/dns/dnsbaselib.php, but now sub-domains shows my IP address home.
I want to setup it for this domain:310blog.com ,and my ip server is 178.162.231.63. ( for example when i make a sub-domain : http://saman.310blog.com/, it shows Kloxo default page )

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! if you want to add a wildcard into your Kloxo admin. You should follow these steps:

1. In your admin panel: Domain Adm->Manage DNS->Add A, in Hostname field you should enter:

> *

And in Value field:

> YOU_IP_ADDRESS

When you press add, maybe you face with invalid_subdomain error. If this happens, you should edit "dnsbaselib.php" in /usr/local/lxlabs/kloxo/httpdocs/htmllib/lib/dns/dnsbaselib.php, from your server, and remove this condition from line 104,

```
// Validates subdomain
if (!preg_match("/^(([a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$/", $param['hostname'])) {
throw new lxexception('invalid_subdomain', 'hostname');
}
```

After that retry first step.

1. After step one, you need to edit httpd.conf in this path: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf, and add this :

> ```
> <VirtualHost YOUR_IP_ADDRESS:80>
> ServerName YOUR_DOMAIN.com
> ServerAlias *.YOUR_RDOMAIN.com
> DocumentRoot /home/DOMAIN_DIR/YOUR_DOMAIN.com/
> DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.shtml index.htm default.htm Default.aspx Default.asp index.pl
> ScriptAlias /awstats/ /home/kloxo/httpd/awstats/wwwroot/cgi-bin/
> SuexecUserGroup USERNAME USERNAME </VirtualHost>
> ```

You have to use your IP address instead of YOUR_IP_ADDRESS, your domain name instead of YOUR_DOMAIN.com, your domain folder instead of DOMAIN_DIR and your username instead of USERNAME. 
3. after that restart your httpd service.

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

Comment: for second step i used this link: http://www.davidosajie.com/wildcard-dns-with-kloxo/